# How to use `paste0` with a vector name to the end in R in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working on a `paste0` code using `for loop` and a vector's name.
I want to make a vector become like

```
[chr] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But `paste0` is usually used with each of vector's values like this

```
paste0("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
```

So I'm confused how I can make this with vector's only name `ds`.
Below is what I tried but returned only `1`

```
ds <- c("1","2","3","4","5")

 for (i in 1:length(ds)) {
    ans <- paste0(ds[i])
  }
  
 ans
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for:

```
paste('[chr] ', paste(ds, collapse=' '), sep='')
# [1] "[chr] 1 2 3 4 5"
```

or:

```
cat('[chr]', paste(ds, collapse=' '))
# [chr] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Using a `for` loop we can do

```
ans <- '[chr]'
for (i in ds) ans <- paste(ans, i)
ans
# [1] "[chr] 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Comment: I'm looking for the second one..!

Comment: Oh I mean the result I'm looking for is one `chr` formation like the second one! But the code must include `for loop` and `paste0`  Can you give me a hint related to that?

Comment: @lililililililili Please check update with `for` loop.

Comment: @lililililililili Out of curiosity, what does abbreviation `ans` stand for?

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn’t obvious. 
I checked your answer, thanks. But it seems a little bit different from what I intended, since I have to make a result like this
`caca<-c("1", "2", "3")'
'paste0(caca[1],caca[2],caca[3])'
'[1] "123"'

But with
1. `for loop`
2. `paste0`

I feel really sorry to waste your time… I’ll try on my own based on what you told me

Comment: @lililililililili Use `ans <- '[1]'`.

Comment: `ans` and the numbers on the question are just random combinations, since I thought I can't just upload my whole work here to ask for entire help. Those are structured to show the same problem I face

Answer (score 1):

Loop: As you asked for a specific loop answer. You can simplify the loop:

```
ds <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
ans <- NULL #Delete existing answer if exists
for (i in ds) {
  ans <- paste(c(ans, i), collapse=" ")
}
ans
# [1] "1 2 3 4 5"
```

Base no loop:

```
paste0(ds, collapse = " ")
# [1] "1 2 3 4 5"
gsub(",","",toString(ds))
```

Tidyverse Stringr:

```
stringr::str_flatten(ds, " ")
stringr::str_c(ds, collapse=" ")
```